# create_directory("/MyPath/.MyFolder") is not creating directory; expected that a hidden directory is created

Tags: c++, boost, directory, boost-filesystem

I want to create a hidden directory in Boost 1.7.3 . When I try :

```
boost::filesystem::create_directory("/MyPath/.myFolder");
```

It doesn't work, it does nothing. I tried looking at the doc, but I can't find an answer.

Comment: 1) "Doesn't work" = ?; 2) "Does it work" if using '/MyPath/OtherFolder'?

Comment: No folder is created and there is no error too. Yes it works without the dot.

Comment: And in the case when using a 'non-dot' name? That is; is the issue related to a [hidden on *ix] .name, or is there another issue with using create_directory like that?

Comment: It only doesn't work when I add a dot. But, that's what I want to do.

Comment: Curious: a leading dot really shouldn't matter *shrug*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I'm just stupid. I'm developing in Ubuntu and I used command ls to verify if my directory was created, but this command doesn't show hidden files. ll does. It was working since the beginning.

Comment: Just for info, `ll` is not a different command. It still uses `ls` but with some options. `ls -a` is the option you need (`ll` is probably something like `ls -ltrah` or so). Check what `ll` is on your system by typing `type ll`